# Toad for Cloud doesn't list Cql3 created objects in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, toad

I'm trying Cassandra v1.2.3 on ubuntu and created KeySpace and objects using both cli and cqlsh interfaces.

When connected Toad for cloud to this Casandra node, to query and insert data, found that none of the cql3 created objects through cqlsh not shown except for cli created objects.

Could anyone please let me know how to make Toad for Cloud to see those objects or it is not supported yet?

Answer (score 0):

It apears that toad only supports thrift and not the binary protocol`'CQL'`, but have a look at [this](http://toadforcloud.com/index.jspa#video-2) tutorial containing a demo on using cassandra with toad.